# Converting array variable in powershell to a comma delimited list

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell code which retrieves some data from the database, the declared data type is an array.

```
    @my_data = @()
    
    $x = (invoke-sqlcmd -serverinstance x -database y -Query "select name from first_table")
    $y = (invoke-sqlcmd -serverinstance xx -database yy -Query "select name from second_table")
    $my_data = $x + $y
    $my_data = $my_data | select -unique
    $my_data = "Tom Tim Jo"
    $required_format = "Tom,Tim,Jo"
```

In the example above, I require the format to be comma delimited, at the moment its space delimited.

The issue is that a function that I am passing `$my_data` to requires it to be comma delimited.

I have tried to use `-join ','` as suggested on other SO pages and examples to no avail, as the variable isn't getting comma delimited.

Answer (score 2):

The .Net method Replace() will work

```
$my_data.Replace(' ',',')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting `$my_data` first.

```
$required_format = my_data -split " " -join ","
```